# Rest API url to get product details

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I am getting WooCommerce Product details using REST API. Here is the url I am using,

```
https://squatwolf.com/wc-api/v3?id&name&permalink&short_description&price&sale_price
```

It is not showing me the right products. What could be wrong with my request?

Comment: what response do you get ? wrong means what ? and you are not passing any field param value?

Comment: Yes I am not passing the value

Comment: any reason for not passing?does it has default behaviour so such case? whats actual and expected response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you've not called the right end point. Try

```
https://squatwolf.com/wc-api/v3/products?id&name&permalink&short_description&price&sale_price
```